# Tuple<{type 1}, {type 2}> as a Class?

Tags: c#-4.0, tuples

I currently have a tuple where I have 2 types in it. A `tuple<List<Test>, Int32>`.

How would I construct a Class for that same type of aspect that the Tuple would do?

Any information on that and/or example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking.  Do you want to know how to create an instance of `Tuple`?  Are you wondering how to create your own `Tuple`?

Comment: Maybe you want something like

    public Class Foo
    {

    public List<Test> Tests { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }

    }

Comment: @Shad If he/she really wants to mimic Tuple, then rather `public Class Foo { public List<Test> Item1 { get; set; } public Int32 Item2 { get; set; } }`

Comment: **@Csaba toth**, agree. It will be an exact imitation.

Comment: I already have a tuple and it's working but I'm wondering and considering if I can do it in classes instead. If so, then how would that be done? It's the Item1, Item2, Item3, etc that I do not like and why I am considering changing it.

Comment: If a Class contains a List...and other classes that are not a List would it show up in a WSDL as an array? What i'm looking for is akin to a header record, a List of like a cars object, and a footer which contains the number of cars. Right now, I have that exact thing in a tuple but in the wsdl it's somewhat not intuitive in that its showing Item1, Item2, Item3, etc.

Comment: Nevermind all, I got it figured out using an answer to another question here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274973/creating-a-class-of-objects-within-an-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question using the following answered question: [Creating a Class of Objects within an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274973/creating-a-class-of-objects-within-an-object)

I had to change a few of the dynamics and returns from a tuple to the object value and worked out the serialization aspects.

Thanks for all the information though and very much appreciated.

Comment: And dont forget to override Equals and GetHashCode, that's what make Tuples special.